# How I load another ListView according to item Selected

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, listviewitem

Hello I have some problem with my code ,I would like to display my 2nd list but from the 1st list select the problem that the 2nd list is dependent on the column select for example my first list contains the categories of the product when I click on a category it must display a list contains products of selected categories, I created 2 table 1 ere contains categorie and 2 eme contains product if possible you can help me

Class of Cateegorie

```
public class CategorieActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    ListView listview;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorie);
        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        listview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //DBConnections db=new DBConnections(this);

        DBConnections myDbHelper = new DBConnections(this);
        try {
            myDbHelper.createDatabase();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {
            myDbHelper.openDatabase();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){

            throw sqle;
        }
        ArrayList arrayliste=myDbHelper.getAllrecord();


        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(CategorieActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayliste);
        //<String> myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(CategorieActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categorie));
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent myIntent=new Intent(CategorieActivity.this,ListSatutsActivity.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("Categorie",listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        listview.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```

class of DataBase

```
public class DBConnections extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBName="LastusStauts.db";
    public static final int version=1;
    public final static String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.hp.latestsatuts/databases/";
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    public DBConnections(Context context) {

        super(context, DBName,null, version);

        this.myContext=context;
        Log.v("Error","Appel au constructeur");
    }
    public void createDatabase() throws IOException
    {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist)
        {
            Log.v("DB Exists", "db exists");
            // By calling this method here onUpgrade will be called on a
            // writeable database, but only if the version number has been
            // bumped
            //onUpgrade(myDataBase, DATABASE_VERSION_old, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        boolean dbExist1 = checkDataBase();
        if(!dbExist1)
        {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try
            {
                this.close();
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }

    }
    //Check database already exist or not
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        boolean checkDB = false;
        try
        {
            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DBName;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            checkDB = dbfile.exists();
        }
        catch(SQLiteException e)
        {
        }
        return checkDB;
    }
    //Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the system folder
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {

        InputStream mInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DBName);
        String outFileName = DATABASE_PATH + DBName;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[2024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer)) > 0) {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }
    //delete database
    public void db_delete()
    {
        File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH + DBName);
        if(file.exists())
        {
            file.delete();
            System.out.println("delete database file.");
        }
    }
    //Open database
    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException
    {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DBName;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public synchronized void closeDataBase()throws SQLException
    {
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase myDataBase) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase myDataBase, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
    public ArrayList getAllrecord(){

        ArrayList arraylist=new ArrayList();
        // Pour lire a partir de base de donnees
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        //Cursor notre structure pour deplacer

        Cursor res =myDataBase.rawQuery("select * from Categories",null);
        res.moveToFirst();
        while(res.isAfterLast()==false){
            arraylist.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("Categorie")));
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return arraylist;
    }
}
```

Comment: You got error ?

Comment: I can't quite understand what you say. Which one is your 1st list and which is your 2nd? And 2 tables?

Comment: Your ListStatusActivity class?

Comment: my first list is CategoriesActivity et my 2 is ListStatusAcitivty

Comment: I would like to display my 2nd list but from the 1st list select the problem that the 2nd list is dependent on the column select for example my first list contains the categories of the product when I click on a category it must display a list contains products of selected categorie

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar  it is empty I have not created yet because I have a problem to link categorie with status